# Fullscreen issue with widescreen monitor

Tags: windows-xp, display, fullscreen

I have a Samsung SA300 LED monitor and recently I am facing an issue.
During startup, the Intel splash screen is not going fullscreen (it previously did)
Also if I am using DOS prompt in Windows XP that also is not coming in full screen.
There are black bars on two sides of the monitor giving me the feeling as if I am using a square monitor.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I need you to tell me: 1- Is a DVI connection or VGA? 2- Which display drivers are you using?. This is easy to configure but I need that info.

Comment: Hi, I am using a VGA connection for the same.

Comment: And the drivers? Nvidia, Intel, ATI?

Comment: Intel drivers..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to be the scaling option, sometimes what's happening to you is desired, lets try first with setting this option in the Intel Graphics Control Panel:
[image]

If you have an older version of intel graphics control panel search for something similar or ask in the comments.